Yammer Embed has stopped loading image modal
I've been using yammer embed on our intranet for a while, A few weeks ago it stopped loading image modal when an image is clicked. Even the configuration site no longer allows the images to load on click. (https://engage.cloud.microsoft/embed/widget?domainRedirect=true)
The same loads correctly when you load viva engage from the browser directly (https://engage.cloud.microsoft/main/feed). But when in embed mode the error appears.
Error says "AuthenticatorContext has not been initialized". When an image is clicked.
I've tried allowing all cookies and nothing seems to change.
